# UNIX Command Line - How to "find" directories using embedded wildcard

Tags: unix, find

I want to find all/any directories on a UNIX Server named `"2"`, but I only want them within a certain directory structure name `"/home/abc/public_html"`.

I tried this:

```
find / -type d -name "/home/abc/public_html/*2"
```

But I got the error

> find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though
>   pathnames do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a condition with `-a`:

```
find . -name '*/home/abc/public_html/*' -a -name '*2'
```

Or, as seen in comments:

```
find / -type d -wholename "*/home/abc/public_html/*2"
```

Because you were getting the error

> find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though
>   pathnames do). That means that '-name */home/vps/public_html/*'' will
>   probably evaluate to false all the time on this system. You might find
>   the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.
>   Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ...
>   -print0 | grep -FzZ */home/vps/public_html/*''."

Comment: got the same error message "find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name `*/home/vps/public_html/*'' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ `*/home/vps/public_html/*''."

Comment: What OS are you working on? See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98445/40596 where they suggest some variations

Comment: CENTOS 6.6 i686 virtuozzo

Comment: What if you try the same with `-wholename` as described in the error message? `find / -type d -wholename "/home/abc/public_html/*2"`

Comment: Thanks @fedotqui. At least I did not get an error message but the command returned nothing. I know there are directories out there

Comment: also I tried the suggested command at your stackexchange link "find -path "/home/abc/public_html/*/2" -print" and it too did not return anything

Comment: @H.Ferrence it is weird. I try all of them with my `find (GNU findutils) 4.5.12` and they work well. What is your `find --version`? Do you get the file if you do `find -name '*2'` alone?

Comment: how can I determine the find version?

Comment: @H.Ferrence type `find --version`

Comment: when I run `find -name '*2'` I get results...not the one I was looking for necessary but at least that variation of the command worked

Comment: find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2

Comment: @H.Ferrence then it might happen that there is no match on this regex. Make sure you are looking for something that does exist : )

Comment: I ran this command at the outset `find / -type d -name "2"` and returned pages of results. A couple of the directories where in the list so I am trying to refine the command to eliminate the dirs I do not care about and simply hone in on the one I do. I am trying to come up with a command I can re-use in the future so that is why I am posting here.

Comment: @H.Ferrence yeah, I understand. `find / -type d -wholename "/home/abc/public_html/*2"` did not return anything to you, maybe because we missed a `*`. What do you get with `find / -type d -wholename "*/home/abc/public_html/*2"`?

Comment: @H.Ferrence did you run the same command I wrote? The error you indicate happens when you don't quote it.

Comment: awesome @fedorqui -- IT WORKED ! I upvoted your comment which is the answer for me

Comment: @H.Ferrence nice, we made it! :) Updating the answer with this information.

Comment: greatly appreciate your help @fedorqui

Comment: @fedorqui Using `-a` is redundant, it's always implied when you don't put a specific operator. Also why `-wholename` over `-path`?